# How to return a list of list in backtracking problem combination sum?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a code to return all subset of a list such that their sum is T. my code print the result correctly but cannot return it in the separate list.
If you can look at my code help me where I did wrong.

```
def combination(ar,summ,index,r):
    if summ<0:
        return

    if summ==0:
        print(r)
        result.append(r)
        return 

    while index<len(ar) and summ-ar[index]>=0:
        r.append(ar[index])
        combination(ar,summ-ar[index],index,r)
        index+=1
        r.pop()

    return result


A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=3
result=[]
print(combination(A,B,0,[]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because when you run function `combination` recursively, the list `r` is reused and not created a new one when appending into `result`. That's why when you print it show correctly but after that you call `r.pop()` it removes all of its value and you get empty lists.

To fix this, simply create a copy of `r` like this:

```
def combination(ar,summ,index,r):
    if summ<0:
        return 

    if summ==0:
        new_result = r.copy()
        result.append(new_result)
        return 

    while index<len(ar) and summ-ar[index]>=0:
        r.append(ar[index])
        combination(ar,summ-ar[index],index,r)
        index+=1
        r.pop()

    return 


A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=3
result=[]
combination(A,B,0,[])
print(result)
#[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [3]]
```